# Superfactorial or Hexation in C++

Tags: c++, factorial

Are there ways to do Hyperfactorial, superfactorial, or Hexation in C++? I was thinking pow pow pow(), but that looks funny.

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{ //the base of the Hexation 
    long double b = 1000; //the raised power. 
    long double c = 2000; //set the initial exponential raise 
    long double E = 6; //need a for loop to roll through the initions of the powers. 

    for (int t = 1; t <= c; t++)
        E = E*b; //print out the results 

    cout << E << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add your code so that we can give you better answer

Comment: #include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//the base of the Hexation
long double b=1000;

//the raised power.
long double c=2000;

//set the initial exponential raise
long double E= 6;

//need a for loop to roll through the initions of the powers.
for(int t=1; t<=c; t++)
E=E*b;

//print out the results
cout << E << endl;

return 0;

}

Comment: is there a way to format that?

Comment: ??...what do you mean? ananswer, or you saying an answer?

Comment: so did you see the code? just want to know what methods and functions can be used and do I need to use the <c.math> library instead. I am sorry what math operators can be used...

Comment: @JCSMOOTH345 forget my comments, they were actually nonsense, and I have deleted them. Don't post complementary information about your question in a comment, but edit your question. There you have many formatting possibilities.

Comment: okay, what other ways could this be done and does this example do the same thing?

Comment: anyone still around...

Answer (score -1):

First thing you'll need is a library for working with very large numbers. Otherwise you might as well just have a lookup table of results as there will only be at most 10 that can be stored in a double (for hyper/super factorial).

Hyperfactorial: Just implement this the obvious way. Iterate up to a number, adding i*i to the value as you go.

```
double hyperfact(int N) {
    double ret = 1.0;
    for (; N > 1; N--) {
        ret *= pow(N, N);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Superfactorial has more than one definition. Again just implement it the obvious way.

```
double superfact_sloane(int N) {
    double ret = 1.0;
    for (; N > 1; N--) {
        ret *= factorial(N);
    }
    return ret;
}

// Will only actually return values for N = 1,2.
// Anything greater than 2$ = inf
double superfact_pickover(int N) {
    double nfact = factorial(N);

    double ret = nfact;
    for (int i = 1; i < nfact; i++) {
        ret = pow(ret, nfact);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Hexation I can't see any purpose for, not even tetration is in use in mainstream mathematics. Again just do it the obvious method.

```
double tetration(double x, int N) {
    double ret = x;
    for (; N > 1; N--) {
        ret = pow(x, ret);
    }
    return ret;
}

double pentation(double x, int N) {
    double ret = x;
    for (; N > 1; N--) {
        ret = tetration(x, ret);
    }
    return ret;
}

double hexation(double x, int N) {
    double ret = x;
    for (; N > 1; N--) {
        ret = pentation(x, ret);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

In all cases the maths is completely pointless.

Comment: Your entire answer is basically "the solution is obvious". Not particularly helpful, is it?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, the mathematical definitions are themselves pseudocode. Short of actually writing the solutions (which is completely pointless anyway) you can't make it any easier to implement.

Comment: You seem to have missed the purpose of answering questions on Stack Overflow. "I can do it; it's so easy; it's obvious; it's pointless to explain because it's so easy" is not an answer. Thanks.

Comment: The point of SO is not to provide code samples on request though. Sure a lot of my answer might sound like "it's obvious", but it also says "get a bignum library", "look at the maths definitions" and "there aren't any shortcuts I know of for computing them". What more do you want, other than trivial code snippets?

Comment: An intuitive and thoughtful explanation of the problem and the possible solutions.

Comment: okay so...what is the answer to the question....I am very confused now....I just want to know are there other ways to do Hexation in C++...and did I do it right from the beginning....

Comment: I will probably have to use big double though...tge numbers even with small numbers are huge

Comment: Im trying to make a calculator for mobike is why I wanted to know how would this be accomplished... It probably goiñg to be a bit more to it...but I at least have an idea.

Comment: An that is the link to exactly what I was aiming for...which seems to be this...which is notation for A sub N..